# Rspec Capybara Suite Timing out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

We have a large test suite (full build usually takes 15 minutes to run) that 2 days ago started timing out and we have not been able to run a full build since then.  I added a config to the rails_helper to force specs to fail if they take too long to run:

```
config.around(:each) do |example|
    Timeout::timeout(10) {
      example.run
    }
end
```

We finally ran a full build yesterday with this config, but with over 60 failed specs!  The specs run, and pass, in isolation.

Our DatabaseCleaner is set as follows:

```
config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
end


config.before(:each, js: true) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end

config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

In specs that have been generally flakey, we have a few sleeps.

Unfortunately when I run the build and watch the test logs, nothing interesting is outputted to help me debug.

I think the last noteworthy information is our gemfile setup.  Here are our test group gems:

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara-screenshot', '1.0.10'
  gem 'capybara', '2.4.4'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '3.2.0'
  gem 'capybara-webkit', '1.3.1'
  gem 'launchy', '2.4.3'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.46.2'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '1.3.0'
end
```

Has anybody experienced issues like this before?

THANK YOU in advance!!

Comment: Sometimes actual page loading can take more than 10 seconds. I suggest you to set a debugger in `after(:each)` hook and take a screenshot or check opened requests to understand the real reason.

Comment: What changed 2 days ago?  Your selenium-webdriver is a few months out of date, you might need to update that if testing with newer versions of browsers.

Comment: I added an after(:each) screenshot and it is pretty inconclusive.  It shows a rendered page and that is about it.  @TomWalpole I updated our gems and am still getting the timeouts.  I also checked out a commit from 10 days ago, when specs were DEFINITELY running and they are still stalling on me. :(

Comment: @EllieMorris - so if a commit from 10 days ago now doesn't work it has to be something that changed in your testing setup -- for instance a browser being updated, or OS update (What browser are you testing against?)

Comment: We have the same issue, the weird thing is that it also breaks on the CI server which is a totally different setup. We also can build a commit from two months ago.

Comment: The timeouts also started on the same day as this stackoverflow issue was created, is this a coincidence?

Answer (score 1):

Whelp, it turned out that updating all the test gems and adding the following line to our rails_helper was the answer:

`Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.block_unknown_urls
end`

I unfortunately am not clear as to why this was our fix but the build completed for the first time in 2 days.

Comment: We have the same issue, unfortunately adding the `block_unknown_urls` does not help for us.